# Selecting a search's sort-type while on a phone call adds a small black bar to the bottom of the screen

Tags: bug, user-interface, ios-app

In the iOS app, if you change the sort-type for a search while on a phone call, it will add a small black bar to the bottom of the page.

[image: Searching the Overwatch tag]

[image: Changing the sort type]

[image: Now there's a black bar]

- App Version: 1.6.5.4
- Device: iPhone 6
- OS Version: Version 10.3.1 (Build 14E304)